# Using sed, put quotes around words of varying length

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file with records (csv); I would like to go through each lines, find words of varying lengths that are alpha and put quotes around.

File content is:

```
12345, astringofrandomlength, anotherstringofrandomlength, 2019-01-01
12346, moreastringofrandomlength, otherstringofrandomlength, 2019-01-01
```

Desired output would be:

```
12345, 'astringofrandomlength', 'anotherstringofrandomlength', 2019-01-01
12346, 'moreastringofrandomlength', 'otherstringofrandomlength', 2019-01-01
```

I tried the following:

```
sed -e "s/\([A-Za-z]+\)/'\1'/g" datafile.csv
```

where I understand that I specified a group \( \) where I am searching any alpha words [A-Za-z]+ and I wish to replace using a backreference '\1' between, for each occurences of the said words in each line. But this is not working, so I am definitely missing something.

From one data file to another the fields where such words would be found will vary in position and amount, such as:

```
12345, astringofrandomlength, 800, anotherstringofrandomlength, stringy, 2019-01-01
12346, moreastringofrandomlength, 980, otherstringofrandomlength, stringzz, 2019-01-01
```

Comment: Escape `+` or use `\{1,\}` instead. Or use `-E` option and use `(...)` instead of `\(...\)`

Comment: What about words with alpha number characters `astringofra666ndomlength`.  What about words with  quotes in them `astrin'gofrand'om'length` what about ones with spaces in them `astir ngofra ndoml ength` Doesn't follow any CSV rules I've seen.

Comment: @x15 you are right: I was working with a compromise where I would not put quotes around integers or numeric fields for instance, which would be ok for most of my case but not ideal as you suggested. I was hoping to fix one problem at a time but am open to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is a POSIX BRE pattern that matches a letter and a *literal `+` sign* because an unescaped `+` in the POSIX BRE pattern matches a literal plus symbol.

You may fix the issue by using either of

```
sed -e "s/\([[:alpha:]]\+\)/'\1'/g" datafile.csv # GNU sed required
sed -E "s/([[:alpha:]]+)/'\1'/g" datafile.csv
sed "s/[[:alpha:]]\{1,\}/'&'/g" datafile.csv
```

See [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/w7dgaq)

Note the first one is a GNU sed solution, the second one uses the POSIX ERE syntax and the second one uses a POSIX BRE `\{1,\}` range quantifier that matches 1 or more repetitions. Note the `&` in the replacement pattern in the third example inserts the whole match (no capturing group needed).

Comment: So this is working (thank you!)  except that spaces in stringsofrandomlengths are getting a quote too. Is there a possibility to somewhat exclude spaces from the process?

Comment: @EtienneGodin Then your text is different from what you provided. Try `sed "s/[[:alpha:]]\([[:alpha:][:space:]]*[[:alpha:]]\)\{0,1\}/'&'/g" file` or `sed -E "s/[[:alpha:]]([[:alpha:][:space:]]*[[:alpha:]])?/'&'/g" file`, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/DjQaq7),

Answer (score 1):

[This answer addresses x15's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59057741/using-sed-put-quotes-around-words-of-varying-length#comment104355038_59057741)
and the OP's [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59057741/using-sed-put-quotes-around-words-of-varying-length#comment104355165_59057741).] Suppose the CVS file consists of one line with *three* values:

```
12345, Beethoven's 9th\, finale, 1824-05-07
```

And the goal is to produce:

```
12345, 'Beethoven\'s 9th, finale', 1824-05-07
```

where:

- The number and date are not quoted
- The middle value is incased in single quotes
- The `'s` is escaped to `\'s`
- The `\,` is unescaped to just `,`
- And where we assume that no value is broken into two or more lines.

We also assume that, excluding the first and last values in a line:

- a blank value is given by `, ,` (one space)
- a value consisting of a single space is given by `,  ,` (two spaces)
- `,    a   ,` gives a value with leading and trailing spaces (typically a bad thing)
- and two adjacent commas `,,` is an illegal construct

and that similar rules pertain to the first and last values of a line.

First it is convenient to remove all escaped commas by temporarily replacing them with some string not found in the file.  I would normally with GNU **sed** use a control-A with `\x01` (or type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>), but here we will use `XXX` for display purposes.  It is also helpful to replace all single quotes with some special string.  So we need:

```
sed "s/\\\,/XXX/g"
sed "s/'/YYY/g"
```

(As an aside, the choice of single quotes complicates the **bash** parsing; double quotes would have been more straight-forward.)  (You may also want to replace escaped-escapes, `\\`, but we don't do that here.)

Next it is convenient to temporarily add a comma-space to the start of every line, so that every value can be matched by the regular expression `, [^,]*`:

```
sed "s/^/, /"
```

Next we single-quote all the values, and then remove the quotes from the numbers and dates:

```
sed "s/, \([^,]*\)/, '\1'/g"
sed "s/, '\([0-9][0-9]*\)'/, \1/g"
sed "s/, '\([0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}\)'/, \1/g"
```

Finally, replace the special codes for the commas and single quotes, and remove the temporary initial comma-space:

```
sed "s/XXX/,/g"
sed "s/YYY/\\\'/g"
sed "s/..//"
```

Putting this all together, broken out into small chunks for debugging purposes, we get:

```
cat example.txt                     |\
sed "s/\\\,/XXX/g"                  |\
sed "s/'/YYY/g"                     |\
sed "s/^/, /"                       |\
sed "s/, \([^,]*\)/, '\1'/g"        |\
sed "s/, '\([0-9][0-9]*\)'/, \1/g"  |\
sed "s/, '\([0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}\)'/, \1/g" |\
sed "s/XXX/,/g"                     |\
sed "s/YYY/\\\'/g"                  |\
sed "s/..//"                        |\
cat -
```

Comment: **Edit:** CSV, not CVS.

Comment: Can I recommend that you chain together multiple sed expressions with multiple `-e` options, rather than pipes? Each pipe is a little more system resources applied to your job. The only advantage this approach has over a single `sed` process is that it spreads your `sed` threads onto multiple CPUs .. which almost certainly will not compensate for the performance hit you'll see from the overhead of the pipes.

Comment: @ghoti: You are quite right. The multiple seds here are only for debugging purposes, to make it easy to add and delete lines, and maybe use **tee**.

Comment: @JosephQuinsey Your post was really helpful to advance my understanding of sed use.